# Sandbox post; do what you like here if you want to test out formatting, etc

Tags: discussion

I'm posting this for my own benefit as well as for others' - feel free to answer, edit, comment anything you like (as long as you keep it civil, of course!).

This is the place to try out new formats, etc, without disrupting any other activity on the site.

---

This was converted into an edit from an answer

## Note:

Unfortunately, the PGN viewer is unavailable on meta.chess. In order to play around with it, you will need to start a [new question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on the main site, but not actually post it. Note that the viewer preview updates as you type. Basic info on the viewer can be accessed [here](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/179/86).

Answer (score 4):

Here are some common formats to know about:

## Big -> `#Big`

<sup>superscript</sup> -> `<sup>superscript</sup>`

<sub>subscript</sub> -> `<sub>subscript</sub>`

*italics* -> `*italics*`

*italics* -> `_italics_`

**bold** -> `**bold**`

**bold** -> `__bold__`

***bold italics*** -> `***bold italics***`

***bold italics*** -> `___bold italics___`

`gray monospace` -> use the ` character (backtick) around text

*`italics monospace`* - use asterisks *around* backticks.

Same with **`bold monospace`**

## *Big italics*

tag replications:

[interesting](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interesting) -> `[tag:interesting]`

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) -> `[meta-tag:status-declined]`

If you use this format in comments, the tags become links without the graphic: [status-declined](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined)

---

horizontal line - `---`

> quote - `>quote`
>
> > nested quote - `>>nested quote`

Line break = 2 spaces then enter
Like this.

Hover over the following:

> Spoiler text - `>!Spoiler text`

<s>Yes, I know that the gray backtick formatting looks weird in the spoiler quote; that's probably a bug.</s> The bug is squished.

Comment: As a lot of rep is needed to edit posts on meta, and edit suggestions are disabled (therefore, we can't look at the source), it's really useful to put the code into the post.

Answer (score 3):

> Inside a normal, happy quote, `monospace works as expected`.

But

> Inside a secretive, spoiler quote, `monospace becomes evil and wicked`.

Comment: 'Tis fixed as of [yesterday](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228441/164012).

Answer (score 2):

Just curious whether or not the PGN viewer is active on meta.

```
[FEN ""]

1.c4 e5
```

Apparently not.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Event "Second Piatigorsky  Cup"]
[Site "Santa Monica  USA"]
[FEN " w - - 0 1"]
[Date "1966.07.27"]
[EventDate "1966.07.17"]
[Round "7"]
[Result "1-0"]
[White "Bent Larsen"]
[Black "Petrosian"]
[ECO "B39"]
[WhiteElo "?"]
[BlackElo "?"]
[PlyCount "59"]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 g6 5. Be3 Bg7 6. c4 Nf6
7. Nc3 Ng4 8. Qxg4 Nxd4 9. Qd1 Ne6 10. Qd2 d6 11. Be2 Bd7
12. O-O O-O 13. Rad1 Bc6 14. Nd5 Re8 15. f4 Nc7 16. f5 Na6
17. Bg4 Nc5 18. fxg6 hxg6 19. Qf2 Rf8 20. e5 Bxe5 21. Qh4 Bxd5
22. Rxd5 Ne6 23. Rf3 Bf6 24. Qh6 Bg7 25. Qxg6 Nf4 26. Rxf4
fxg6 27. Be6+ Rf7 28. Rxf7 Kh8 29. Rg5 b5 30. Rg3 1-0
```

Test post for using the viewer.

Comment: Sorry Alan - it appears the viewer does not work in the sandbox. I commented on your question, and edited the sandbox to note that the viewer must be tested on the main site, and this is legitimately possible in an *unposted* new question.