# How to insert move comments in the replayer

Tags: support, pgn-viewer

I am unable to figure out how to put move comments into the PGN file here. I have tried putting them within `{  }` after the move, but they get ignored. I also looked at the games posted by others, but none seem to have comments.

Does the replayer here does not support comments? The discussion here [How do I add a replayer to my post?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/how-do-i-add-a-replayer-to-my-post) seems to suggest that it does.

Comment: I've now highlighted the part of the post that you link to which points out that comments aren't functional yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to insert comments is a feature of the PGN viewer that Andrew created; however, comments are not currently enabled on chess.SE's implementation of the PGN viewer. At some point (I don't know when exactly) there should be a rebuild of the site which will incorporate the features such as comments and arrows/highlighting into the PGN viewer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I was worried I had missed something.