# What enhancements do we need for the replayer?

Tags: feature-request

[We expressed the need for a replayer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/can-we-implement-a-replayer-for-chess-analysis-on-the-site/), and thanks to [Andrew's replayer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/169/672) and [balpha's implementation](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/175/672), this is now [totally operational](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/180/672). Awesome, how could it be better ?

**How could it be better ?**

> This initial version is a starting point for discussion. Please let me know what makes sense, what doesn't, what could be improved, etc. (Almost) nothing is set in stone yet.

Answer (score 2):

**Initial display of an arbitrary position** in the variations tree.

[Here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/650/672), a position is asked for analysis, with a few history moves. I edited<sup><sup>-pending-</sup></sup> the question for it to include the background moves mentionned in the following text, but the result of it is readers must go through the moves to see the position the question is really about. “The position shown” can't make sense anymore.

The workaround is obviously not to include the moves and only display the final position, but having such a nice replayer and not including the background moves in it would be rather disappointing.

Comment: The first example at @Andrew's github demo page for the replayer appears to exhibit exactly this behavior (if I understand correctly what you're after). I'm not sure of the usage, though, or whether this is a feature that is currently implemented at chess.SE in any case (in the same vein as `{PGN comments}`).

Comment: Oh, interesting, I didn't went there to notice it. The source says `[StartPly "13"]` (under `[Title …]` in place of `[FEN "…"]`), I'll try it out. […] It seems syntactically allowed (the replayer is still displayed), but not taken into any consideration, even though I did not try it from a starting position  (and from the post preview).

Comment: [StartPly], [StartFlipped], and [Title] are all things that I added in a more recent version than the one on the site (so they're not active here).  If the replayer is updated, I'll post a full explanation of all 3 in the [meta-tag:faq] post.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of [in-depth](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/634/672) [analysis](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/654/672) could make good use of **comments inside variations**, at least assessing final positions results. [Here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/1629/672), I tricked¹ the engine with no-break spaces, so it would consider my comments (`-+`, etc.) as part of the previous move², but it feels like a hack.

[I read](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/180/672) comments belonged to curly braces, but are not displayed yet. Looks like the way to go ?

---

*Or* it would be *great* to be able to insert target points inside the variation, and refer to these targets from within the text explanations on the side. *Clicking on the in-text reference would make jump to the corresponding position in the diagram.* But that sounds like asking way too much.

¹ I feel sad for tricking such a nice engine :(
² That makes them highlighted in final positions, which might be desirable, but rather done on purpose.

Comment: I just wanted to add some of my thoughts to your post here:
First, you are correct that comments usually go in `{braces}` but are not currently supported. 
Second, the non-breaking spaces will add a space visually between the move and the evaluation (eg. `1. e4 +-`), but usually there is NOT a space there (eg. `1.e4+-` is more common).  Finally, take a look at [NAGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_Annotation_Glyphs), you can get the same result with `1. e4 $18`.

Comment: Also, the idea you have about target points is great, that's not currently supported at all because of how the replayer was designed to be self-sufficient and not interfere with other parts of the page, but it's a cool idea.

Comment: I'm a french typographer, I sow spaces :·) (for [some reasons](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/4401/1514)). NAGs are interesting, thanks ! I'm afraid they're just as supported as comments, i.e. not ?

Comment: NAGs are fully supported right now :)

Comment: Ah, I see that, great, thanks. For the further interested reader, by default, they are right next to the move, but you can still space them out with an unbreakable space before an actual space before the dollar sign : `1.e4␣ $13` (`␣` being unbreakable).

Answer (score 0):

Support hiding moves for the purpose of puzzles.

Not sure how other sites do it but I assume a custom PGN tag.