# Can i post an annotated PGN chess board in chess.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, pgn-viewer

I know that i can post FEN Image, that is Static diagram of chess board. But can i post interactive game or sequence of moves here in stackexchange?

Comment: Yes you can post an interactive game. Search on meta PGN viewre and you shall find instructions. Best regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we implement a replayer for chess analysis on the site?](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/3/can-we-implement-a-replayer-for-chess-analysis-on-the-site)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  See [balpha's answer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/175/12) for specific directions.

[This post with additional instructions](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/279/12) might also be helpful.