# Interactive diagrams starting from a certain move in a game

Tags: feature-request

In relation to one of the [previous questions](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279/tool-used-to-create-chess-analysis-interactive-diagrams-in-many-chess-stack-exch) on interactive diagrams, I would like to ask whether it is possible for a game to start with the let us say 33. move?

For example, I would like to make a diagram of the following segment of the 9.round game of the Curacao Candidates Tournament 1962 between Fischer and Geller (please see [the relevant question on CSE](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/14354/fischer-vs-geller-curacao-candidates-1962)):

```
[Event "Curacao Candidates"]
[Site "Willemstad CUW"]
[Date "1962.05.16"]
[Round "9"]
[White "Robert James Fischer"]
[Black "Efim Geller"]
[Result "0-1"]
[ECO "B88"]
[EventDate "1962.05.02"]
[PlyCount "136"]
[FEN "6k1/6p1/4p2p/5r2/2R5/7P/6P1/6K1 b - - 0 33"]

33...Kf7 34.g4 Rf3 35.Kg2 Rd3 36.Rc7+ Kf6 37.h4 Ra3 38.Rb7 Rc3 39.g5+ hxg5 40.hxg5+ Kg6 41.Re7 Re3 42.Kf2 Re5 43.Kf3 Rf5+ 44.Ke3 e5 45.Ke4 Rxg5 46.Re8 Rg1 47.Kf3 Rf1+ 48.Kg3 Rf5 49.Rb8 Kg5 50.Re8 Kf6 51.Rf8+ Ke6 52.Re8+ Kf6 53.Rf8+ Ke6 54.Re8+ Kd5 55.Ra8 Rf7 56.Kg4 Re7 57.Ra5+ Ke6 58.Ra6+ Kf7 59.Kf3 Re6 60.Ra8 e4+ 61.Ke3 g5 62.Ra1 Kg6 63.Rb1 Re5 64.Kd4 Kf6 65.Re1 Ra5 66.Rxe4 Kf5 67.Re8 Kg4 68.Ke3 Kg3 0-1
```

However, the above PGN does not appear as a diagram if the game starts with 33...Kf7. However, if you just change 33...Kf7 to 1...Kf7 a diagram appears. I guess i should then change all move numbers so that the pgn starts with 1... etc. Is there a way around this? If not, can it please be made possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can already do this.

Paste the full PGN of the game.  Then you can add a header "StartPly" which says which half move to start with.

For example, to start with white's move 33, you could do `[StartPly "65"]` and include that in the game headers.  If you have a StartPly, you should include the FEN of the game start (`[Fen ""]`) as opposed to the FEN of the position in question.

Incidentally, I already edited the linked question, so you can also look at that to see how I changed the markdown.

Comment: Andrew: Thank you, both for the answer and the edit. The solution seems elegant enough. Cheers.

Comment: Note (to self): make sure you leave a blank line between the PGN headers and the moves. Otherwise the StartPly header won't work.

Comment: What if the asker did not have the prior moves? Even if they did, they shouldn't have to type them all.

Comment: @RosieF if you don't have the prior moves then you can use the FEN tag as in the OP.  The lichess analysis board will let you move pieces and very easily get the FEN for any given board position.

Comment: Agreed. But the OP's problem was with the move-numbers. It should be possible to make the viewer work even if the move numbers don't start with 1.

Comment: @RosieF indeed that'd be useful! It seems to work for move numbers below 10, see [here](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/695/3594) for more details.