# PGN Viewer not working for me- what have I done wrong?

Tags: support, pgn-viewer

I asked [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40450/how-to-remove-annoying-bishop-on-h3) question just now and the PGN viewer won’t appear. I have read some posts in meta under the tag [pgn-viewer](/questions/tagged/pgn-viewer) and specifically the thread [Tool used to create chess analysis interactive diagrams in many chess stack exchange answers](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279/tool-used-to-create-chess-analysis-interactive-diagrams-in-many-chess-stack-exchange). I had problems in my past questions also. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used clever quotes rather than normal quotes and you added an extra space. I've fixed it for you.

Comment: I don’t know what a clever quote is, but thanks!

Comment: @insipidintegrator Your quote had a slight angle on it. Some programs like Word will automatically change your text to those angled quotes while you're typing.