# How a new player like me, can upload a game?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I played a game and I did some mistakes that I see now, but I want to know If I right, but how I can upload the png file to here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we implement a replayer for chess analysis on the site?](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/3/can-we-implement-a-replayer-for-chess-analysis-on-the-site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instructions for including your game's pgn in a post on the main site can be found in answer's to [this meta question](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/179/167).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was using the beta :/