# How do you hide links within a few words or a phrase?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

The question says it all as to what I want to know. I know it is possible, as I have seen a person edit my spot before to make it happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [your recent answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/23855/7792), it seems you want to add a link description. You can use the link markdown like

`[Demonstration](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=e4_d5_exd5_Qxd5_Qh5_Qxa2_Qxh7_Qxa1_Qxh8_Qxb1_Qxg7_Qxb2_Qxg8_Qxc2_Qxf7_Kd8_Qxf8_Kd7_Qxe7_Kc6_Qxc7_Kd5_Qxc8_Qxc1_Ke2_Qxd2_Kf3_Qxf2_Kg4_Qxf1_Qxb8_Qxg1_Qxa8_Qxh1_Qxa7_Qxh2_Qxb7_Ke5_Qf3_Qxg2_Kh4_Qxf3_Kg5_Qg4_Kxg4)`

to show the link as

[Demonstration](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=e4_d5_exd5_Qxd5_Qh5_Qxa2_Qxh7_Qxa1_Qxh8_Qxb1_Qxg7_Qxb2_Qxg8_Qxc2_Qxf7_Kd8_Qxf8_Kd7_Qxe7_Kc6_Qxc7_Kd5_Qxc8_Qxc1_Ke2_Qxd2_Kf3_Qxf2_Kg4_Qxf1_Qxb8_Qxg1_Qxa8_Qxh1_Qxa7_Qxh2_Qxb7_Ke5_Qf3_Qxg2_Kh4_Qxf3_Kg5_Qg4_Kxg4).

---

However, perhaps you might be interested in converting your external link chess diagram to [replayer, our on-site chess diagram](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179) by copying the generated PGN and FEN as a code-block, like

```
[Event "Chessboard Editor at Apronus.com"]
[Site "https://www.apronus.com/chess/wbeditor.php"]
[Date "2019.02.28"]
[Round "-"]
[White "?"]
[Black "?"]
[Result "*"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Qxd5 3. Qh5 Qxa2 4. Qxh7 Qxa1 5. Qxh8 Qxb1 6. Qxg7 Qxb2 7. Qxg8 
Qxc2 8. Qxf7+ Kd8 9. Qxf8+ Kd7 10. Qxe7+ Kc6 11. Qxc7+ Kd5 12. Qxc8 Qxc1+ 13. 
Ke2 Qxd2+ 14. Kf3 Qxf2+ 15. Kg4 Qxf1 16. Qxb8 Qxg1 17. Qxa8 Qxh1 18. Qxa7 Qxh2 
19. Qxb7+ Ke5 20. Qf3 Qxg2+ 21. Kh4 Qxf3 22. Kg5 Qg4+ 23. Kxg4 *
```